# Try to make the audio frequency analyser in javascript

Tags: javascript, audio

adobe audition has the audio frequency analyser.
But it need some people to see.
I want to make the similar function in javascript.
Just put .mp3 file and run  will get the most times of frequency.
In below, I put 600hz pure audio in adobe audition.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHJ8m.png)

```
const AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext
const audioCtx = new AudioContext()
const gainNode = audioCtx.createGain()
const analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser()
const audio = new Audio('./600hz.mp3')
const source = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(audio)

source.connect(analyser)
analyser.connect(audioCtx.destination)

gainNode.gain.value = 1
analyser.fftSize = 1024
analyser.connect(gainNode)

const fftArray = new Uint8Array(analyser.fftSize)
analyser.getByteFrequencyData(fftArray)
audio.play()

const timer = setInterval(() => {
    const fftArray = new Uint8Array(analyser.fftSize)
    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(fftArray)
    console.log(fftArray)
}, 100)

setTimeout(() => {
    clearInterval(timer)
}, 2000)
```

In fact, I don't know so many knowledge about audio.
Hope someone give me advise.
Thanks.